# KAFKA / AWS MSK, unable to reset consumer group offset

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I'm having problem trying to reset offset for my consumer group, running on AWS MSK (2.3.1 (Commit:18a913733fb71c01)). I tried the kafka-consumer-group.sh and tried to reset the topic partition offset to 6200 and the result show NEW_OFFSET as 6200 as well. But when I describe the consumer group offset, it still can see that particular partition still using old offset.

Below is my consumer group current state, as you can see from below for partition 0, the CURRENT-OFFSET is 4467

```
GROUP                TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID                                            HOST            CLIENT-ID
sms-service-consumer send_sms        5          4446            6263            1817            kafka-node-client-015192c7-dc87-4677-8ab4-0a62ad73626f    kafka-node-client
sms-service-consumer send_sms        2          4458            6282            1824            kafka-node-client-015192c7-dc87-4677-8ab4-0a62ad73626f    kafka-node-client
sms-service-consumer send_sms        3          4457            6282            1825            kafka-node-client-015192c7-dc87-4677-8ab4-0a62ad73626f    kafka-node-client
sms-service-consumer send_sms        4          4460            6277            1817            kafka-node-client-015192c7-dc87-4677-8ab4-0a62ad73626f    kafka-node-client
sms-service-consumer send_sms        1          4461            6289            1828            kafka-node-client-015192c7-dc87-4677-8ab4-0a62ad73626f    kafka-node-client
sms-service-consumer send_sms        0          4467            6294            1827            kafka-node-client-015192c7-dc87-4677-8ab4-0a62ad73626f   kafka-node-client
```

I run below command to reset to 6200

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <broker> --group   sms-service-consumer --reset-offsets --execute --topic send_sms:0 --to-offset 6200
```

and getting below response

```
GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  NEW-OFFSET
sms-service-consumer           send_sms                       0          6200
```

However when i describe the consumer group, I'm still getting old CURRENT-OFFSET

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <broker>  --group sms-service-consumer --offsets  --describe


GROUP                TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG             CONSUMER-ID     HOST            CLIENT-ID
sms-service-consumer send_sms        5          4446            6263            1817            -               -               -
sms-service-consumer send_sms        2          4458            6282            1824            -               -               -
sms-service-consumer send_sms        3          4457            6282            1825            -               -               -
sms-service-consumer send_sms        4          4460            6277            1817            -               -               -
sms-service-consumer send_sms        1          4461            6289            1828            -               -               -
sms-service-consumer send_sms        0          4467            6294            1827            -               -               -
```

Appreciate if anyone can shred some light!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [this](https://gist.github.com/marwei/cd40657c481f94ebe273ecc16601674b) to reset your consumer group?
If so two notes:

1. you're not passing the consumer group name in your reset command (check your call just after the `--group` parameters
2. As per notes on [here](https://gist.github.com/marwei/cd40657c481f94ebe273ecc16601674b)

> The consumer group must have no running instance when performing the reset. Otherwise the reset will be rejected.

Does your consumer group have running instances when you're trying to reset it?

Comment: Sorry my bad, 
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <broker> --group sms-service-consumer    --reset-offsets --execute --topic send_sms:0 --to-offset 6200 , this is the command that i execute.

Comment: Yes, i've kill the consumer group before i execute the command, else it would get rejected.